# Dashboard - SQL Server Backups

Tags: datatables, dashboard, scom, backups

I am looking to create a dashboard with the SCOM information collected about the last SQL database backups for **ALL** server instances within the Operations Manager.

1. Where does SCOM store the data for MSSQL on Windows: Database

- Database backup status (Yes, Monitor has been enabled)

2. What tables are utilized to compare and generate alerts?

I have looked at the OperationsManager database for different tables - can't seem to find the correct table that provides Server Name, Database Name, Backup Dates (latest/oldest)

Have tried different scripts, but only picks up local database information - not all the databases that are being monitored within SCOM.